# How can I translate SVG group element to the center of the root SVG?

Tags: svg

**Question:** How can I translate the center of a SVG group element to the center of the root SVG. I tried to use `transform="translate(x,y)"` on the `<g>` element, but this transformation will only translate with respect to the top left corner of the group element.

**Example case and goal:** In the following SVG, the two rectangles `<rect>` are grouped together with `<g>`. **Assume we don't know the position, size, and which types are elements are inside the group. We only know the width/height of the parent SVG.** Goal is to translate the center of the group (bounding box of the two rectangles) to the center of the root SVG. The issue is that we don't know the height/width of the "bounding box" which is the group itself, thus when using `transform="translate(x,y)"` alone won't get us to the center of the root SVG.

```
<svg width="500px" height="300px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0,0,5.0,3.0">
    <g transform="translate(0,0)">
        <rect x="1" y="0.25" width="0.5" height="0.5" fill="green" />
        <rect x="1.25" y="1" width="0.5" height="0.5" fill="red" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

**Requirements:**

- The solution can only use pure SVG. CSS or external libraries can NOT be used.
- Using Python to do basic calculation is okay. However, remember we don't what elements are inside the `<g>`.
- The coordinate system for the root SVG (viewBox, width, height) must not be change because in example use case, these coordinate system are used for conversion of real world spatial units (ex: millimeters) to pixels for the end application.

[image]

Comment: iterate through the contents of the <g> and calculate the overall bounding boxes. You can do that in python assuming all you have in there are rect elements.

Comment: Assumption is that I don't know what elements are inside the <g>, thus I can't iterate though each element. If I did that, I would have to use another library in Python to parse SVG and it would complicate things. I posted this question hoping that there would be some transformation trick, or modifying the coordinate system for the <g> element in order to achieve the end goal.

Comment: @Zythyr did you find any solution?

Comment: This solution should work for you, or at least provide a way forward: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56400874/910328

Answer (score 3):

You need some way to do calculations. I'm using Javascript:

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
// the viewBox of the svg element splited
let svgVB = svg.getAttribute("viewBox").split(/[ ,]+/);


let o = test.getBBox();
let oCenter = {};//the center of the g#test element
oCenter.x = o.x + o.width/2;
oCenter.y = o.y + o.height/2;

// the valuefor the transform attribute
let tr = `
translate(${-oCenter.x},${-oCenter.y})
translate(${svgVB[2]/2},${svgVB[3]/2})`;


test.setAttributeNS(null, "transform",tr);


// for debugging I'm drawing the bounding box 
bbox.setAttributeNS(null, "transform",tr);

function drawRect(o, parent) {
  let rect = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'rect');
  for (let name in o) {
      rect.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
  }
  parent.appendChild(rect);
  return rect;
}

drawRect(o, bbox);
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg width="500px" height="300px" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0,0,5.0,3.0">
  <g id="bbox"></g>
    <g id="test" transform="translate(0 0)">
        <rect x="1" y="0.25" width="0.5" height="0.5" fill="green" />
        <rect x="1.95" y="1" width="0.5" height="0.5" fill="red" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: You are not only using Javascriot, but also the API function `.getBBox()`. For that you need 1. a renderer that actually _computes_ the size and position of the contained elements and 2. an implementation of that API. It works in a browser, but is far beyond "basic computations in in Python".